# Transfer DateTime to .NET WebAPI

Tags: android, .net, datetime, android-date

I would like simply get Android current time and pass to .NET WebAPI. That is it. But there are many approaches...

I tried this one

**Android side**

```
String TimeOfRequest =  Long.toString(new Date().getTime());
```

**.NET side**

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
t = epoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(locationItem.TimeOfRequest));
```

But it gives this result

> 0001-01-02 18:01:34.0366112

Please suggest about simplest approach to do it.

Comment: which date format you want?

Comment: @HemantParmar US  MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: I think it's the best approach. It may due to new Android Date. Try java.uitl.Date: `String TimeOfRequest =  Long.toString(new java.util.Date().getTime());`

Comment: @Jacky Well I already have it implemented...

Comment: Then it's quite weird, because I tested on javafiddle.leaningtech.com and https://dotnetfiddle.net/ Does it affected by other part? How do you use `t` value after `epoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(locationItem.TimeOfRequest));`

Comment: @Jacky Thats what I am asking for :) I need solution to convert android time to Windows datetime.

Comment: Transfer the date in ISO format, which is standard. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. Then convert it to whichever format you like to display it.

Comment: In this case, `System.DateTime t = epoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(locationItem.TimeOfRequest));` and then `Console.WriteLine("{0}, t.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`

Comment: @NoiseGenerator, which ISO standard are you referring to? Your example string is not exactly ISO 8601, though it looks similar (ISO 8601 would have a `T` rather than a space between the date and the time of day).

Comment: @OleV.V. ISO 8601: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`. Right, I forgot the `T` and also `TZD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private String formatDate(long milliseconds) /* This is your topStory.getTime()*1000 */ {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
    return sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Passing a recognizable text rather than an unreadable millisecond value is a good idea. Now you are at it, I recommend a text in ISO 8601 format, like `2017-12-11T07:37:47.462Z`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, assume your API is correct, meaning you passing string from Android mobile to ASP.net API correctly.

```
String TimeOfRequest =  Long.toString(new Date().getTime());
//TimeOfRequest = "1512977867949" // For example
```

In your API:

```
// For example locationItem.TimeOfRequest = "1512977867949";
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var t= epoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(locationItem.TimeOfRequest));

Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")); // print "12/11/2017 07:37:47"
Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().ToString()); // print "System.DateTime"
```